# Android socket always ending in timeout

Tags: java, android, sockets, timeout, connection

I have made an android socket client application for android 2.3.3.
It sends a XML request, and then recieves an answer back from a cobol socket server.

The application works perfectly fine, my problem is that, once my client application has read all the data, it still hangs around, waiting for the timeout limit for some reason.

Heres the code:

```
Socket socket = new Socket(serverIpAddress, serverPort);
socket.setSoTimeout(2000);

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

String request = ("Some XML Request");
out.println(request);
out.flush();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
Log.d("Nicklas", "Reader Oprettet");
Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
int i = 0;
Boolean KeepGoing = true;
while (KeepGoing)
{

    try 
    {
        String lol = in.readLine();
        if (lol == null) { KeepGoing = false; }
        v.add(new String(lol));
        i++;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("NickEEEXX", e.toString());
        KeepGoing = false;
    }                       
}
```

It always ends in the catch, with the exception "java.net.SocketTimeoutException" - even if it has sent and recieved the right data. This slows down the program a lot.

I am running this code as a method, not a thread, becouse i need to change the GUI in this section.

Does anyone have any ideas why it waits for the timeout?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `lol` is not `null` when there's no more data. Try checking against a blank string.

Comment: I tried 'if (lol == "") { KeepGoing = false; }' too, no difference.

Comment: **I've figured one way to fix this. The XML reply i get back always ends with </Answer>, so i simply ask if lol (the variable for readline) contains that. **

Comment: You know you can't do '==' operator on Strings, right? I also miss that sometimes.

Comment: But you're right, knowing the end tag and checking if you have that makes perfect sense.